# Using shared runners to access the gitlab registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ci-runner

I am fairly new to using the gitlab runners, so I decided to read some of the documentations on them before using them, however, the more I read, the more confused I got. One of the stages in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` should be a building stage, in which I want to have a runner build everything and hopefully push the image to the gitlab registry. From what I understood, I should be using docker-in-docker and before I start the actual build, I should first log in, where my first question came:

```
services: docker:dind
image: docker:git
before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

In all of the documentations, that I read, there was little to no information on the tokens. I saw that, when I register a new gitlab-runner, I get a special token for it, but what about using the shared runners? How do I get access to their tokens and do I even need to? I also read that there are some [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html), which also include the `CI_BUILD_TOKEN` and the `CI_REGISTRY`. Does this mean that they are already defined and I should not be defining them myself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the registry as a first step - https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/

Once this is done you can use the $CI_BUILD_TOKEN and $CI_REGISTRY variables - you definitely don't want to provide your own values for these!